# Converting an entire dierectory to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a .bat file that would go through an entire directory of folders and sub folder and convert all the .avi files to another directory with the same structure of folder names and file names. This is what I wrote, but it's not running properly:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%a in (*.avi) do (
    set "sourcePath=%%~dpa"
    set "relativePath=!sourcePath:~1!"
    set "destinationPath=..\Converted\!relativePath!"
    set "destinationFile=!destinationPath!%%~na.mp4"
    
    mkdir "!destinationPath!" 2>nul
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -preset superfast -crf 28 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p "!destinationFile!"
)

echo Conversion complete.
pause
```

Where is the mistake here and what can I do to fix it.

When I run the script it goes through each file in the source directory and spits out this error below:

```
Error opening output .\Converted\:\Users\xxx\FG01_3MOS_baseline_2022-05-30\05-45-19.mp4: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Are you sure, you *have* a folder named `.\Converted\:\Users\xxx`? I doubt it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to not waste time defining variables, and then use just ```md "..\Converted%%~pa" 2>nul```, then ```ffmpeg -i "%%a" -preset superfast -crf 28 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p "..\Converted%%~pna.mp4"```? Doing that, you'd also be able to forego the `EnableDelayedExpansion` instruction too!